# Check file exists with dynamic name

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I've a file with dynamic name with version like `Abc.1.0.zip`, `Abc.2.0.zip`. I want to check if file exists irrespective of version. I tried

```
find -name "Abc(.*).zip"
```

But this does not consider regular expression. Also with `find`, I need to get result and check if count greater than 1 then can use that variable in condition.

Is there any simple method in shell script which returns boolean in single line like `fileExists Abc.1.0.zip`?

Comment: like `test -f Abc*.zip` ?

Comment: Cross-posted on SO - [Check file exists with dynamic name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62572114/5291015)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For find(GNU) to use regular expression , you should use `-regex` option like :

```
find . -regex ".*Abc.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.zip"
```

Also , you can mention different regex type using `-regextype` option along with `-regex`

> **valid types are** ‘findutils-default’, ‘awk’, ‘egrep’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’,
> ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’,
> ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’.

Using `find` , you can execute commands for each file/files found using `-exec` option . So , if the file found then it executes the command you provide.

Ex:

```
$ find . -regex ".*Abc.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.zip" -exec file {} \;
./Abc.1.0.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
./Abc.2.0.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

To test if the file exists in shell , you could use like :

```
[[ -f "Abc.1.0.zip" ]] && echo "File exists" || echo "File Not Exists"
```

Comment: Please quote the regexes/globs in find, otherwise the `*` might be expanded before `find` gets a chance of seeing it.

Comment: Thanks this helped!